# How to remove a directory in docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

It seems that `rm -rf` in docker container works only with files.

```
docker run ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'sudo rm  -rf ./mydir; ls'
```

it lists `mydir` among directories without printing any errors.

I use ubuntu 14.04 for host and image.

**EDIT:**

I thought that the bug appeared after I had added another file to the directory, but I was mistaken. Finally, changing storage driver helped to solve the issue.

Comment: how did mydir get there? the default ubuntu does not have that dirrectory and your command is not mounting any volumes in?

Comment: remove -f flag, it might give you the hint for rm failure.

Comment: @Usman Ismail via docker run ubuntu git clone ...

Comment: Can you give the full list of steps to reproduce. There is nothing specific about deleting directories inside docker. That being said permissions and volume mounting are relevant so we need bull steps to reporduce the problem.

Comment: @lonewasp Thanks, but there are no errors anyway.

Comment: @Usman Ismail Ok, I'll try.

Comment: try a full path, rm -rf with relative paths is bad unless you are 1000% positive of where you are at.

Comment: I would suspect docker invocation of bash to eat part of your command up to ls - try writing this as a script, placing it into container and run the script. Or run in interactive mode.

Comment: @lonewasp Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: sudo docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash -c 'rm -r /media; ls /' works and gives:
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var [Docker version 1.0.1, build 990021a]

Comment: At least in last sample there is a little mess polygon -> polygon... then run ubuntu, then polygon again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you can't seem to remove a directory, here are two possibilities:

1. **User confusion between images and containers.** Each `docker run` creates a new container, and any changes in containers, like removing a directory, or running something that modifies the file system, are isolated from the original image, and all other containers.
2. [**Aufs** layering bug/feature](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1672). Look at `docker info` to see if you are using Storage Driver aufs or imagemapper. To reinstall docker to use imagemapper: backup any irreplaceable, unique images to tar files, remove docker.io, install lxc-docker from the ppa as described in the [official install docs](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/) and change `/etc/default/docker` to contain `DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper"`

It is also probably an anti-pattern to commit directories and then remove them because that data may still be in there somewhere. Even if it disappears from the file system, it could still be wasting space internally.

Docker images are built in layers, each commit is a layer.
To see this, try `docker history <image>` to see what is in your image.

The first case is deserving of a short, simple example, but it looks like you are possibly experiencing the second case.

## Images vs. Containers and removing directories

Let's create a private image called `mystuff` from `ubuntu:14.04` and, later below, try to rm -rf /opt:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
root@435e68479c5b:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@435e68479c5b:/# exit
$ docker commit 435e6 mystuff
```

Let's look inside (`-t` is only used here for pretty printing on one line):

```
docker run -t mystuff ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Now let's try to remove `/opt` (usually that is optional stuff, safe to remove):

```
docker run -t mystuff rm -rf /opt
```

And then look inside for it, and it is still there!!! (seems like the reported problem):

```
docker run -t mystuff ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

What happened?

- each time `docker run mystuff` is used, it makes a **new container** from the image `mystuff`
- Changes to the image are not committed unless you use docker commit

If you look in the container, the changes are there:

```
docker ps -a
... lots of stuff...
e9e8be13d928        mystuff:latest              "rm -rf /opt"          2 minutes ago        Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                                  nostalgic_archimedes
```

Get a tarball out and look for opt, grep it for dir beginning with opt, it isn't there!:

```
docker export e9e8 | tar tv | grep ^opt
```

Note:  `e9e8` is particular to my run of this example. To refer to a container, you can use part of the hex string from `docker ps` in the first col.

Now I commit the container that has the rm -rf change into a new image `noopt`:

```
docker commit e9e8 noopt
```

And look inside a container created from noopt:

```
docker run -t noopt ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

And sure enough, opt is gone!

But because docker images are in layers, distributing noopt will include /opt in an earlier historical image, so you can't keep other people from getting it back:

```
docker history noopt
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE
bc4e69f9e871        59 minutes ago      rm -rf /opt                                     0 B
d198d23dab38        About an hour ago   /bin/bash                                       3 B
04c5d3b7b065        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD [/bin/bash]               0 B
d735006ad9c1        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/   1.895 kB
70c8faa62a44        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/polic   194.5 kB
c7b7c6419568        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:d4aab24fc178303dc0   192.5 MB
511136ea3c5a        18 months ago                                                       0 B
```

To get back to the layer before /opt was removed, we just need to pick out d198d... and run it

```
docker run -t d198d23dab38 ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Summary:

- Docker has containers and images.

  - Images are intended to be more permanent.
  - Images are created in layers called *commits*, similar in concept to git repositories
  - Containers are created from images, and changes in containers are not kept in images (unless explicitly committed)

Docker also has a great build system that should have been used here.  Whoever wrote that script should instead learn about `docker build` and write a proper Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I'm indeed using aufs. I recreated the image from scratch and the problem didn't appear. I'll check your solution.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I think this is a good question, and may help other people too.

Comment: Very nicely detailed answer. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 2):

If permission is denied while trying to delete directory try to delete it with root user.
Container must be started in order to run this command.

```
docker exec -u root -it <CONTAINER_NAME/ID> rm -rf <DIRECTORY_TO_DELETE>
```

Comment: "-u root" was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted files inside the docker container using **rm -r -f** command

Answer (score 1):

To remove a directory "to_remove" from a container from /

```
docker exec -t <container_name/container_id> /bin/sh 'rm -rf to_remove'
```

To remove the files from the directory to_remove from a container

```
docker exec -t <container_name/container_id> /bin/sh 'rm -rf to_remove/<file_name>'
```

To remove all the file from the directory to_remove from a container

```
docker exec -t <container_name/container_id> /bin/sh 'rm -rf to_remove/<file_name>'
```

To remove a directory "to_remove" from a container from /path/target_dir/  *not tested*

```
docker exec -t <container_name/container_id> /bin/sh 'rm -rf /path/target_dir/to_remove/'
```